# Generalizing a data.frame subsetting function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a toy data.frame that has 4 columns (`study`,`outcome`,`group`,`time`). Say, a user wants to know in which unique `study` values any of the other selected column values are constant or vary.

For example, if user wants to know in which unique `study` values, `outcome` and `group` column values are constant or vary, then we know 4 situations are possible:

1. `group`   is constant but `outcome` varies.
2. `outcome` is constant but `group`   varies.
3. `outcome` & `group` both vary.
4. `outcome` & `group` both don't vary.

Function `foo` below, is exactly based on the above example.

**Question:** I wonder how to generalize `foo` such that user can input the names of the his selected columns (e.g., `outcome` and `group`) in the function, and `foo` automatically examines in which unique `study` values any of the selected columns are constant or vary?

*ps. In the below example, my generalized function will produce the same output as shown below.*

```
h = "
study outcome group time
a     1       1     0
a     2       1     1
b     1       1     0
b     1       2     0
c     2       1     0
c     3       2     1
d     1       1     0
d     1       1     0
e     1       1     0"
h = read.table(text=h,h=T)

foo <- function(dat, cond) {
  
  switch(cond, 
         
         `1` = dat %>% 
           group_by(study) %>%
           filter(n_distinct(group) == 1, n_distinct(outcome) > 1) %>%
           ungroup,
         `2` = dat %>% 
           group_by(study) %>%
           filter(n_distinct(group) > 1, n_distinct(outcome) == 1) %>%
           ungroup,
         
         `3` =  dat %>% 
           group_by(study) %>%
           filter(n_distinct(group) > 1, n_distinct(outcome) > 1) %>%
           ungroup,
         `4` = dat %>% 
           group_by(study) %>%
           filter(n_distinct(group) == 1, n_distinct(outcome) == 1) %>%
           ungroup )  } 

#------------------- EXAMPLE OF USE:
> foo(h, 1)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  study outcome group
  <chr>   <int> <int>
1 a           1     1
2 a           2     1
> foo(h, 2)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  study outcome group
  <chr>   <int> <int>
1 b           1     1
2 b           1     2
> foo(h, 3)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  study outcome group
  <chr>   <int> <int>
1 c           2     1
2 c           3     2
> foo(h, 4)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  study outcome group
  <chr>   <int> <int>
1 d           1     1
2 d           1     1
3 e           1     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input argument is unquoted, use `{{}}`

```
foo <- function(dat, study_col, group_col, outcome_col) {
  
  fn1 <- function(cond) {
           switch(cond, 
         
         `1` = dat %>% 
           group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
           filter(n_distinct({{group_col}}) == 1, n_distinct({{outcome_col}}) > 1) %>%
           ungroup,
         `2` = dat %>% 
           group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
           filter(n_distinct({{group_col}}) > 1, n_distinct({{outcome_col}}) == 1) %>%
      ungroup,
         `3` = dat %>% 
           group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
           filter(n_distinct({{group_col}}) > 1, n_distinct({{outcome_col}}) > 1) %>%
      ungroup,
         
         `4` = dat %>% 
           group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
           filter(n_distinct({{group_col}}) == 1, n_distinct({{outcome_col}}) == 1) %>%
      ungroup
         )  }
     purrr::map(1:4, ~ fn1(.x))

}
```

-testing

```
> foo(h, study, group, outcome)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  study outcome group  time
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 a           1     1     0
2 a           2     1     1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  study outcome group  time
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 b           1     1     0
2 b           1     2     0

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  study outcome group  time
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 c           2     1     0
2 c           3     2     1

[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  study outcome group  time
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 d           1     1     0
2 d           1     1     0
3 e           1     1     0
```

---

Or use

```
foo2 <- function(dat, study_col, group_col, outcome_col) {

    dat %>%
           dplyr::select({{study_col}}, {{group_col}}, {{outcome_col}}) %>%
           dplyr::group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(grp = stringr::str_c(n_distinct({{group_col}}) == 1, 
              n_distinct({{outcome_col}}) == 1 ))   %>%
           dplyr::ungroup(.) %>%
           dplyr::group_split(grp, .keep = FALSE)  



}
```

-testing

```
> foo2(h, study, group, outcome)
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    study  : character
    group  : integer
    outcome: integer
  >
>[4]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  study group outcome
  <chr> <int>   <int>
1 c         1       2
2 c         2       3

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  study group outcome
  <chr> <int>   <int>
1 b         1       1
2 b         2       1

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  study group outcome
  <chr> <int>   <int>
1 a         1       1
2 a         1       2

[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  study group outcome
  <chr> <int>   <int>
1 d         1       1
2 d         1       1
3 e         1       1
```

Comment: Sure will look into it

Comment: @rnorouzian the second part is simple.  You can add the `select(-time)` before the `group_by`

Comment: @rnorouzian REgarding the first part, the `group_by` can be done before the loop as well, but the `filter` conditions are different

Comment: @rnorouzian yes, those are changed to a single group_split

Comment: @rnorouzian yes, that is possible.  can you post as a new question. thanks

Comment: @rnorouzian in the example data, which is the var2_col

Comment: @rnorouzian wouldn't it better to have an example with more columns so that it can be tested as well