# Follow-up: Generalizing a data.frame subsetting function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm following up on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68551304/7223434). In [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68551304/7223434), the `foo` function helped the user to know in which unique `study` values any of the *two other selected columns* (`group`&`outcome`) are *constant* or *vary*. In that case, 4 situations (2^2) were possible:

1. `group`   is constant but `outcome` varies.
2. `outcome` is constant but `group`   varies.
3. `outcome` & `group` both vary.
4. `outcome` & `group` both don't vary.

Function `foo2` below was offered to extract rows for `study` that met each of the above 4 possibilities.

In this follow-up, I was wondering if we can extend `foo2` function by perhaps adding a `...` argument so user can input one or more `var_col` (e.g., var1_col, var2_col,...), and then function will extract the possible situations (`number of variable^2` situations)?

For example, in my below data, I have `4` selected columns (`sample`,`group`,`outcome`,`control`) and thus `8` possible situations exist to be extracted from this data by a new function.

I understand `number of variable^2` quickly increases if a user adds multiple variables, so I want to extend `foo2` function to just a few more variables.

```
h = "
   case sample group outcome control
1     1      1     1       1       1
2     1      2     1       1       1
3     1      1     2       1       1
4     1      2     2       1       1
5     1      1     1       2       1
6     1      2     1       2       1
7     1      1     2       2       1
8     1      2     2       2       1
9     2      1     1       1       1
10    2      1     2       1       1
11    2      1     1       2       1
12    2      1     2       2       1
13    3      1     1       1       1
14    3      2     1       1       1
15    3      1     1       2       1
16    3      2     1       2       1
17    4      1     1       1       1
18    4      2     1       1       1
19    4      1     2       1       1
20    4      2     2       1       1
21    5      1     1       1       1
22    5      1     2       1       1
23    6      1     1       1       1
24    6      1     2       1       1
25    7      1     1       1       1
26    7      2     1       1       1
27    8      1     1       1       1
28    9      1     1       1       1
29    9      2     1       1       1
30    9      1     2       1       1
31    9      2     2       1       1
32    9      1     1       2       1
33    9      2     1       2       1
34    9      1     2       2       1
35    9      2     2       2       1
36    9      1     1       1       2
37    9      2     1       1       2
38    9      1     2       1       2
39    9      2     2       1       2
40    9      1     1       2       2
41    9      2     1       2       2
42    9      1     2       2       2
43    9      2     2       2       2
44   10      1     1       1       1
45   10      1     2       1       1
46   10      1     1       2       1
47   10      1     2       2       1
48   10      1     1       1       2
49   10      1     2       1       2
50   10      1     1       2       2
51   10      1     2       2       2
52   11      1     1       1       1
53   11      2     1       1       1
54   11      1     1       2       1
55   11      2     1       2       1
56   11      1     1       1       2
57   11      2     1       1       2
58   11      1     1       2       2
59   11      2     1       2       2
60   12      1     1       1       1
61   12      2     1       1       1
62   12      1     2       1       1
63   12      2     2       1       1
64   12      1     1       1       2
65   12      2     1       1       2
66   12      1     2       1       2
67   12      2     2       1       2
68   13      1     1       1       1
69   13      1     2       1       1
70   13      1     1       1       2
71   13      1     2       1       2
72   14      1     1       1       1
73   14      1     2       1       1
74   14      1     1       1       2
75   14      1     2       1       2
76   15      1     1       1       1
77   15      2     1       1       1
78   15      1     1       1       2
79   15      2     1       1       2
80   16      1     1       1       1
81   16      1     1       1       2"
h = read.table(text=h,h=T)

foo2 <- function(dat, study_col, group_col, outcome_col) {

    dat %>%
           dplyr::select({{study_col}}, {{group_col}}, {{outcome_col}}) %>%
           dplyr::group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(grp = stringr::str_c(n_distinct({{group_col}}) == 1, 
              n_distinct({{outcome_col}}) == 1 ))   %>%
           dplyr::ungroup(.) %>%
           dplyr::group_split(grp, .keep = FALSE) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to add 3 dots at the end, capture it as symbols in `ensyms`, then convert it to string (`as_string`), make the only change by looping `across` those columns, create a logical condition with `n_distinct` and paste (`str_c`) with `reduce`, while pasteing the other columns as well (could be simplified in a single `across` as well) and then use `group_split` on the final 'grp' column

```
foo2 <- function(dat, study_col, group_col, outcome_col, ...) {
   
    dot_cols <- ensyms(...)
    str_cols <- purrr::map_chr(dot_cols, rlang::as_string)

    dat %>%
           dplyr::select({{study_col}}, {{group_col}}, {{outcome_col}}, !!! dot_cols) %>%
            dplyr::group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
            dplyr::mutate(grp = across(all_of(str_cols), ~ n_distinct(.) == 1) %>%
                   purrr::reduce(stringr::str_c, collapse=""),
                          grp =  stringr::str_c(n_distinct({{group_col}}) == 1, 
                n_distinct({{outcome_col}}) == 1, grp)) %>%
                dplyr::ungroup(.) %>%
                 dplyr::group_split(grp, .keep = FALSE)
           
            }
```

-testing

```
> out <- foo2(h, case, group, outcome, sample, control)
> out
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    case   : integer
    group  : integer
    outcome: integer
    sample : integer
    control: integer
  >
>[14]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 16 x 5
    case group outcome sample control
   <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
 1     9     1       1      1       1
 2     9     1       1      2       1
 3     9     2       1      1       1
 4     9     2       1      2       1
 5     9     1       2      1       1
 6     9     1       2      2       1
 7     9     2       2      1       1
 8     9     2       2      2       1
 9     9     1       1      1       2
10     9     1       1      2       2
11     9     2       1      1       2
12     9     2       1      2       2
13     9     1       2      1       2
14     9     1       2      2       2
15     9     2       2      1       2
16     9     2       2      2       2

[[2]]
# A tibble: 8 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     1     1       1      1       1
2     1     1       1      2       1
3     1     2       1      1       1
4     1     2       1      2       1
5     1     1       2      1       1
6     1     1       2      2       1
7     1     2       2      1       1
8     1     2       2      2       1

[[3]]
# A tibble: 8 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    10     1       1      1       1
2    10     2       1      1       1
3    10     1       2      1       1
4    10     2       2      1       1
5    10     1       1      1       2
6    10     2       1      1       2
7    10     1       2      1       2
8    10     2       2      1       2

[[4]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     2     1       1      1       1
2     2     2       1      1       1
3     2     1       2      1       1
4     2     2       2      1       1

[[5]]
# A tibble: 8 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    12     1       1      1       1
2    12     1       1      2       1
3    12     2       1      1       1
4    12     2       1      2       1
5    12     1       1      1       2
6    12     1       1      2       2
7    12     2       1      1       2
8    12     2       1      2       2

[[6]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     4     1       1      1       1
2     4     1       1      2       1
3     4     2       1      1       1
4     4     2       1      2       1

[[7]]
# A tibble: 8 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    13     1       1      1       1
2    13     2       1      1       1
3    13     1       1      1       2
4    13     2       1      1       2
5    14     1       1      1       1
6    14     2       1      1       1
7    14     1       1      1       2
8    14     2       1      1       2

[[8]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     5     1       1      1       1
2     5     2       1      1       1
3     6     1       1      1       1
4     6     2       1      1       1

[[9]]
# A tibble: 8 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    11     1       1      1       1
2    11     1       1      2       1
3    11     1       2      1       1
4    11     1       2      2       1
5    11     1       1      1       2
6    11     1       1      2       2
7    11     1       2      1       2
8    11     1       2      2       2

[[10]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     3     1       1      1       1
2     3     1       1      2       1
3     3     1       2      1       1
4     3     1       2      2       1

[[11]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    15     1       1      1       1
2    15     1       1      2       1
3    15     1       1      1       2
4    15     1       1      2       2

[[12]]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     7     1       1      1       1
2     7     1       1      2       1

[[13]]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    16     1       1      1       1
2    16     1       1      1       2

[[14]]
# A tibble: 1 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     8     1       1      1       1
```

testing the total rows

```
> sum(map_dbl(out, nrow))
[1] 81
> nrow(h)
[1] 81
```

---

If we want to remove some arguments

```
foo2 <- function(dat, study_col, ...) {
   
    dot_cols <- ensyms(...)
    str_cols <- purrr::map_chr(dot_cols, rlang::as_string)

    dat %>%
           dplyr::select({{study_col}}, !!! dot_cols) %>%
            dplyr::group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
            dplyr::mutate(grp = across(all_of(str_cols), ~ n_distinct(.) == 1) %>%
                   purrr::reduce(stringr::str_c, collapse="")) %>%
                dplyr::ungroup(.) %>%
                 dplyr::group_split(grp, .keep = FALSE)
           
            }
```

-testing

```
>  foo2(h, case, group, outcome, sample, control)
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    case   : integer
    group  : integer
    outcome: integer
    sample : integer
    control: integer
  >
>[14]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 16 x 5
    case group outcome sample control
   <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
 1     9     1       1      1       1
 2     9     1       1      2       1
 3     9     2       1      1       1
 4     9     2       1      2       1
 5     9     1       2      1       1
 6     9     1       2      2       1
 7     9     2       2      1       1
 8     9     2       2      2       1
 9     9     1       1      1       2
10     9     1       1      2       2
11     9     2       1      1       2
12     9     2       1      2       2
13     9     1       2      1       2
14     9     1       2      2       2
15     9     2       2      1       2
16     9     2       2      2       2

[[2]]
# A tibble: 8 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     1     1       1      1       1
2     1     1       1      2       1
3     1     2       1      1       1
4     1     2       1      2       1
5     1     1       2      1       1
6     1     1       2      2       1
7     1     2       2      1       1
8     1     2       2      2       1

[[3]]
# A tibble: 8 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    10     1       1      1       1
2    10     2       1      1       1
3    10     1       2      1       1
4    10     2       2      1       1
5    10     1       1      1       2
6    10     2       1      1       2
7    10     1       2      1       2
8    10     2       2      1       2

[[4]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     2     1       1      1       1
2     2     2       1      1       1
3     2     1       2      1       1
4     2     2       2      1       1

[[5]]
# A tibble: 8 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    12     1       1      1       1
2    12     1       1      2       1
3    12     2       1      1       1
4    12     2       1      2       1
5    12     1       1      1       2
6    12     1       1      2       2
7    12     2       1      1       2
8    12     2       1      2       2

[[6]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     4     1       1      1       1
2     4     1       1      2       1
3     4     2       1      1       1
4     4     2       1      2       1

[[7]]
# A tibble: 8 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    13     1       1      1       1
2    13     2       1      1       1
3    13     1       1      1       2
4    13     2       1      1       2
5    14     1       1      1       1
6    14     2       1      1       1
7    14     1       1      1       2
8    14     2       1      1       2

[[8]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     5     1       1      1       1
2     5     2       1      1       1
3     6     1       1      1       1
4     6     2       1      1       1

[[9]]
# A tibble: 8 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    11     1       1      1       1
2    11     1       1      2       1
3    11     1       2      1       1
4    11     1       2      2       1
5    11     1       1      1       2
6    11     1       1      2       2
7    11     1       2      1       2
8    11     1       2      2       2

[[10]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     3     1       1      1       1
2     3     1       1      2       1
3     3     1       2      1       1
4     3     1       2      2       1

[[11]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    15     1       1      1       1
2    15     1       1      2       1
3    15     1       1      1       2
4    15     1       1      2       2

[[12]]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     7     1       1      1       1
2     7     1       1      2       1

[[13]]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1    16     1       1      1       1
2    16     1       1      1       2

[[14]]
# A tibble: 1 x 5
   case group outcome sample control
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>
1     8     1       1      1       1
```

Comment: I updatd the post as well.  can you check if this is the expected

Comment: @rnorouzian that is the same as `dplyr::select({{study_col}}, {{group_col}}, {{outcome_col}}, !!! dot_cols)` where dot_cols are the only we captured from `...`

Comment: @rnorouzian yes, you can skip those things as well and remove those mutate with the other grp creation.  I was thinking that you need this as for something extra

Comment: You need to do the `n_distinct` separately on those columns

Comment: Hi Arun, just making sure, you have seen [the new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68639537/7223434) you asked me to post. no rush.

Comment: @rnorouzian sorry, i thought you could see the username in the dupe tag.

Comment: @rnorouzian for the new question, should that be a separate function

Comment: @rnorouzian `foo2` already has `...`. what I meant is that your logic is different now

Comment: Sorry I simply meant the last `foo2` function just extended.

Comment: I mean `foo2` can be modified. For example, if old `foo2` function only identified if two selected variables we constant or varied for each unique study, NOW the `new_foo2` will identify if two selected variables are constant, if some rows of one variable is constant for another variable, and finally if the two variables fully vary.