# Follow-up: Generalizing a data.frame subsetting function 2

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm following up on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68568083/7223434). In that answer, the `foo2` function helped the user identify in which unique `study`, any of the *two other selected columns* (`group`&`outcome`) are *constant* or *vary*.

Now, imagine we want to *additionally* identify if there are unique `study` in which *one of the selected variables* (`outcome`) is constant for some rows of *any other selected variables* (`group`).

For example, in `study==14`, `outcome` is constant for some rows of `group`. But in `study==8`, `outcome` is completely varying for all rows of `group`:

```
   study group outcome
17    14     1       6
18    14     2       6
19    14     3       7
20    14     4       7

   study group outcome
9      8     1       2
10     8     2       3
11     8     3       4
```

Is there a way to extend `foo2` to *additionally* identify studies like `study==14`?

```
dat = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/s/main/cf.csv")

study8 = subset(dat, study==8)[1:3]; study14 = subset(dat, study==14)[1:3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could add some conditions with `case_when`

```
foo2 <- function(dat, study_col, ...) {
   
    dot_cols <- ensyms(...)
    str_cols <- purrr::map_chr(dot_cols, rlang::as_string)

    dat %>%
           dplyr::select({{study_col}}, !!! dot_cols) %>%
            dplyr::group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
            dplyr::mutate(grp = across(all_of(str_cols), ~ {
                      tmp <- n_distinct(.)
                      case_when(tmp  == 1 ~ 1, tmp == n() ~ 2, tmp >1 & tmp < n() ~ 3,  TRUE ~ 4)
                      }) %>%
                   purrr::reduce(stringr::str_c, collapse="")) %>%
                dplyr::ungroup(.) %>%
                 dplyr::group_split(grp, .keep = FALSE)
           
     }

foo2(dat, study, group, outcome)
```

Comment: @rnorouzian there was only a single condition iearlier i.e. `n_distinct(.) == 1`.  here, you may need to do this on multiple cases

Comment: @rnorouzian in the first case, it checks whether there is only one distinct element ->1, if all are distinct (`==n()`) ->2, if it is between 1 and all, 3, all other cases 4.

Comment: @rnorouzian that is a default case if no other expression meets.  By default, it woul dbe NA

Comment: @rnorouzian here, we have 3 expressions which already takes 1, 2, and 3.  If you don't want the third expressin, you can remove and add `TRUE ~ 3`

Comment: Dear Dr. Arun, this is a fantastic function. I have one question though, when I try: `dat <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilzl/i/master/j.csv"); out <- foo2(dat, study,group, outcome,time)`, the element `out[[1]]` and `out[[2]]` don't differ from each each other in terms of `study`, `group`, `outcome`, or `time` so I wonder why `foo2()` doesn't merge these together in its output? -- Thanks again.

Comment: Dear Arun, I have asked a question regarding your answer above [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76909742/16762740)