# Reshaping a data.frame by its columns' combinations

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I was wondering how I could my `data` into my expected output?

```
data = expand.grid(time = 0:2, outcome = 1:2,group = c("control","treatment"))

#Expected output:

#time outcome group       
#0    1       "treatment1 - control"
#1    1       "treatment1 - control"
#2    1       "treatment1 - control"
#0    2       "treatment2 - control"
#1    2       "treatment2 - control"
#2    2       "treatment2 - control"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do a group by `paste`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
   mutate(group = as.character(group),
     group = case_when(group =='treatment' ~ str_c(group, outcome),
           TRUE ~ group)) %>%
   group_by(outcome, time) %>%
   summarise(group = str_c(sort(group, decreasing = TRUE), 
      collapse = ' - '), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  outcome  time group               
    <int> <int> <chr>               
1       1     0 treatment1 - control
2       1     1 treatment1 - control
3       1     2 treatment1 - control
4       2     0 treatment2 - control
5       2     1 treatment2 - control
6       2     2 treatment2 - control
```

Comment: @MartinGal actualy, i didn't see the 'time' column in the ouptut.  My mistake

Comment: Hi Arun, may I ask a question about [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642902/7223434)? Just let me know so I can ask a new question? -- Thank you.

Comment: @Reza That was already answered months back.  You can answer a new question

Comment: Sure, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69858350/16760971) is the new question.