# Putting back a missing column from a data.frame into a list of dta.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

My `LIST` of data.frames below is made from my `data`. However, this `LIST` is missing the `scale` column which is available in the original `data`.

I was wondering how to put back the missing `scale` column into `LIST` to achive my `DESIRED_LIST`?

Reproducible data and code are below.

```
m3="
scale study   outcome time ES bar
2       1       1      0   1  8
2       1       2      0   2  7
1       2       1      0   3  6
1       2       1      1   4  5
2       3       1      0   5  4
2       3       1      1   6  3
1       4       1      0   7  2
1       4       2      0   8  1" 
data <- read.table(text = m3, h=T)

LIST <-         list(data.frame(study=c(3,3)    ,outcome=c(1,1)    ,time=0:1),
                     data.frame(study=c(1,1)    ,outcome=c(1,2)    ,time=c(0,0)),
                     data.frame(study=c(2,2,4,4),outcome=c(1,1,1,2),time=c(0,1,0,0)))

DESIRED_LIST <- list(data.frame(scale=c(2,2)    ,study=c(3,3)    ,outcome=c(1,1)    ,time=0:1),
                     data.frame(scale=c(2,2)    ,study=c(1,1)    ,outcome=c(1,2)    ,time=c(0,0)),
                     data.frame(scale=c(1,1,1,1),study=c(2,2,4,4),outcome=c(1,1,1,2),time=c(0,1,0,0)))
```

Comment: Your `LITS` and `DESIRED_LIST` are exactly the same

Comment: Must it be in the same position ie 2nd column ? or it can be at the very end?

Comment: `lapply(LITS, \(x)merge(x, data)[names(data)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you could do:

```
lapply(LITS, \(x)merge(x, data)[names(data)])
```

Comment: Wait, I think your method doesn't work with this data: `data=data.frame(paper=rep(1:2,3:4),sample=c(1:3,rep(4,4)),comp=c(1:3,rep(4:5,c(2,2))),es=1:7); (LIST <- list(data.frame(study=1       ,sample=1       ,comp=1),
             data.frame(study=rep(3,4),sample=rep(4,4),comp=c(4,4,5,5)),
             data.frame(study=c(2,2)  ,sample=c(2,3)  ,comp=c(2,3)))); (DESIRED_LIST <- list(data.frame(paper=1,study=1,sample=1,comp=1),data.frame(paper=rep(2,4),study=rep(3,4),sample=rep(4,4),comp=c(4,4,5,5)),
                     data.frame(paper=rep(1,2),study=c(2,2),sample=c(2,3),comp=c(2,3))))`

Comment: You can answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69867800/16760971).

Comment: Did you notice the problem with your `merge()` solution. For the `data` in my comment above, your solution doesn't produce the `DESIRED_LIST` in my comment above.

Comment: Can you please post a solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69867800/16760971)?

Comment: Well, using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642902/16760971). That is: `data=data.frame(paper=rep(1:2,3:4),sample=c(1:3,rep(4,4)),
                comp=c(1:3,rep(4:5,c(2,2))),ES=1:7,bar=7:1)` an then: `foo2(data, study,sample,comp)`

Comment: @Reza but the data doesnot contain a study column

Comment: Whatever comes first is considered a `study_col`. In this example, `study` is our `study_col`. Maybe focusing on the output is more helpful.

Comment: @Reza what I am saying is that there is no `study` in the data. It only has `paper, sample, comp, ES, bar`

Comment: Here it is: `data=data.frame(paper=rep(1:2,3:4),study=c(1,2,2,rep(3,4)),sample=c(1:3,rep(4,4)),
                comp=c(1:3,rep(4:5,c(2,2))),ES=1:7,bar=7:1)`

Comment: @Reza. I see. You need to change your function. At the very end when doing group split, change `.keep =TRUE` this will solve your problem. You do not have to do anything outside f the function.

Comment: Can you show me what exactly you mean? You mean I set `.keep = TRUE` and then do what?

Comment: @Reza The function you use. Change `.keep = FALSE` to `.keep = TRUE`

Comment: @Reza, theats it. Once you change that, you can run your function `foo2(data, study, time, etc)` and should give you the results that you want. ie your LIST[

Comment: That is not correct! I want when using `foo2(data, study,sample,comp)` to get `DESIRED_LIST <- list(data.frame(paper=1,study=1,sample=1,comp=1),data.frame(paper=rep(2,4),study=rep(3,4),sample=rep(4,4),comp=c(4,4,5,5)),data.frame(paper=rep(1,2),study=c(2,2),sample=c(2,3),comp=c(2,3)))`!!