# Follow-up: Putting back a missing column from a data.frame into a list of dta.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69859813/16760971). My `LIST` of data.frames below is made from my `data`. However, this `LIST` is missing the `paper` column which is available in the original `data`.

I was wondering how to put the missing `paper` column back into `LIST` to achieve my `DESIRED_LIST` below?

I tried the solution suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69859813/16760971) (`lapply(LITS,function(x)merge(x,data)[names(data)])`) but it doesn't produce my `DESIRED_LIST`.

Reproducible data and code are below.

```
m2="
paper     study sample    comp
1         1     1         1
1         2     2         2
1         2     3         3
2         3     4         4
2         3     4         4
2         3     4         5
2         3     4         5"
data <- read.table(text=m2,h=T)

        LIST <- list(data.frame(study=1       ,sample=1       ,comp=1),
                     data.frame(study=rep(3,4),sample=rep(4,4),comp=c(4,4,5,5)),
                     data.frame(study=c(2,2)  ,sample=c(2,3)  ,comp=c(2,3)))

DESIRED_LIST <- list(data.frame(paper=1       ,study=1       ,sample=1       ,comp=1),
                     data.frame(paper=rep(2,4),study=rep(3,4),sample=rep(4,4),comp=c(4,4,5,5)),
                     data.frame(paper=rep(1,2),study=c(2,2)  ,sample=c(2,3)  ,comp=c(2,3)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to loop over the `list` ('LIST'), subset the `data` based with `%in%` on the `paste`ed rows of data and the list element data

```
LIST2 <-  lapply(LIST, function(x) 
    data[do.call(paste, data[names(x)]) %in% do.call(paste, x),])
```

-checking

```
> all.equal(DESIRED_LIST, LIST2, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could briefly tell me how [your function here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642902/16760971) works? My understanding is that it first `group_by()` a `study_col`, and then looks for unique values of each variable, groups them as a list, am I correct?

Comment: @Reza It groups by 'study_col', and then loop `across` all the other columns names passed in the function to create the number of distinct elements (`n_distinct`), then change the count values to 1, 2, 3, 4 in `case_when` depending on whether the n_distinct value count and the number of rows (`n()`), `paste` the columns transformed with `reduce` to a single column and use that as grouping variable to split (`group_split`)

Comment: I already replied to this

Comment: @Reza sorry I don't know about your logic now.  The function was created based on the logic provided months back.

Comment: @Reza when you ask a new question, it should be a new question and not as a follow up to the linked one because people may look at that link and think that the logic is the same and try to construct solutions based on the same logic which is not what you wnted

Comment: In your solution above if there are other unwanted variables in `data` other than `paper`, what should we do? In other words, if we only want to add `paper` from `data` to the data.frames in the `LIST` how can we do that?

Comment: For example, say `data` was: `data=data.frame(paper=rep(1:2,3:4),sample=c(1:3,rep(4,4)),comp=c(1:3,rep(4:5,c(2,2))),es=1:7)` .

Comment: @Reza in that case, just specify the columns along with 'paper' as column names i.e. `LIST2 <-  lapply(LIST, function(x) 
    data[do.call(paste, data[names(x)]) %in% do.call(paste, x), c('paper', names(x))])`