# Follow-up: Putting back a given missing column from a data.frame into a list of dta.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69866157/16760971). My `LIST` of data.frames below is made from my `data`. However, this `LIST` is missing the `paper` column (*the name(s) of the missing column(s) are always provided*) which is available in the original `data`.

I was wondering how to put the missing `paper` column back into `LIST` to achieve my `DESIRED_LIST` below?

I tried the solution suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69866157/16760971) (`lapply(LIST, function(x)data[do.call(paste, data[names(x)]) %in% do.call(paste, x),])`) but it doesn't produce my `DESIRED_LIST`.

A Base R or tidyverse solution is appreciated.

Reproducible data and code are below.

```
m2="
paper     study sample    comp ES bar
1         1     1         1    1  7
1         2     2         2    2  6
1         2     3         3    3  5
2         3     4         4    4  4
2         3     4         4    5  3
2         3     4         5    6  2
2         3     4         5    7  1"
data <- read.table(text=m2,h=T)

        LIST <- list(data.frame(study=1       ,sample=1       ,comp=1),
                     data.frame(study=rep(3,4),sample=rep(4,4),comp=c(4,4,5,5)),
                     data.frame(study=c(2,2)  ,sample=c(2,3)  ,comp=c(2,3)))

DESIRED_LIST <- list(data.frame(paper=1       ,study=1       ,sample=1       ,comp=1),
                     data.frame(paper=rep(2,4),study=rep(3,4),sample=rep(4,4),comp=c(4,4,5,5)),
                     data.frame(paper=rep(1,2),study=c(2,2)  ,sample=c(2,3)  ,comp=c(2,3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

- Please find a solution with the package `data.table`. Is this what you were looking for?

**Reprex 1**

```r
library(data.table)

cols_to_remove <- c("ES")

split(setDT(data)[, (cols_to_remove) := NULL], by = c("paper", "study"))
#> $`1.1`
#>    paper study sample comp
#> 1:     1     1      1    1
#> 
#> $`1.2`
#>    paper study sample comp
#> 1:     1     2      2    2
#> 2:     1     2      3    3
#> 
#> $`2.3`
#>    paper study sample comp
#> 1:     2     3      4    4
#> 2:     2     3      4    4
#> 3:     2     3      4    5
#> 4:     2     3      4    5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**EDIT**

- Please find solution 2 with the package `dplyr`

**Reprex 2**

```r
library(dplyr)

drop.cols <- c("ES")  

data %>% 
  group_by(paper, study) %>% 
  select(-drop.cols) %>% 
  group_split()

#> <list_of<
#>   tbl_df<
#>     paper : integer
#>     study : integer
#>     sample: integer
#>     comp  : integer
#>   >
#> >[3]>
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   paper study sample  comp
#>   <int> <int>  <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1      1     1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   paper study sample  comp
#>   <int> <int>  <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2      2     2
#> 2     1     2      3     3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   paper study sample  comp
#>   <int> <int>  <int> <int>
#> 1     2     3      4     4
#> 2     2     3      4     4
#> 3     2     3      4     5
#> 4     2     3      4     5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hello @Reza, yes there are other alternatives with Base R or tidyverse. As for now, I edited my `data.table` solution so it is functional.

Comment: Please find my edit with a `dplyr` solution

Answer (score 0):

Consider `ave` to create a grouping column (due to repeated rows) and then run an iterative `merge`.

```r
DESIRED_LIST_SO <- lapply(
  LIST,
  function(df) merge(
      transform(data, grp = ave(paper, paper, study, sample, comp, FUN=seq_along)),
      transform(df, grp = ave(study, study, sample, comp, FUN=seq_along)),
      by=c("study", "sample", "comp", "grp")
  )[c("paper", "study", "sample", "comp")]
)

all.equal(DESIRED_LIST, DESIRED_LIST_SO)
[1] TRUE
```

(Consider keeping the unique identifiers, `ES` and `bar` in desired list to avoid the duplicates rows.)

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` solution. First, create a look-up table, `data2`, which contains the four target columns. `mutate(across(.fns = as.numeric))` is to make column type consistent. It may not be needed. Second, use `map` to apply `left_join` to all data frames in `LIST`. `LIST2` and `DESIRED_LIST` are completely the same.

```
data2 <- data %>%
  distinct(paper, study, sample, comp) %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = as.numeric))

LIST2 <- map(LIST, function(x){
  x2 <- x %>%
    left_join(data2, by = names(x)) %>%
    select(all_of(names(data2)))
  return(x2)
})

# Check if the results are the same
identical(DESIRED_LIST, LIST2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: @Reza This solution does not limited to numeric columns. The left_join will work as long as `data` and the data frames in `LIST` have the same joining column types. I added `mutate(across(.fns = as.numeric))` simply because I want to match your example output.

Comment: @Reza You can delete the `mutate(across(.fns = as.numeric))` line and the code will still work. It is just `identical(DESIRED_LIST, LIST2)` will return FALSE because the `paper` column from `data` is integer, while the paper columns in `DESIRED_LIST` is numeric.