# Dividing a data.frame into a list of data.frames based on grouping rules in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list, function, dplyr

Function `foo2()` comes from [THIS GREAT ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642902/7223434). As explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68639537/7223434), `foo2()` is designed to group the input `Data` into groups based on unique `study`s in which one of the selected variables (ex. `var1.var2`) varies for some rows of any other selected variables (`sample_id`).

In the input `Data` below, in `study == Mecartty` rows, `var1.var2` varies for some rows of `sample_id` and `sample_id` varies for some rows of `study`.

For `study == Larson`, we see the exact same pattern. Therefore, `foo2()` should simply group the `Data` into one group including `study == Larson` and `study == Mecartty` together, because `study == Mecartty` and `study == Larson` have exactly the same pattern.

**QUESTION:** I wonder why `foo2()` groups `study == Mecartty` and `study == Larson` into 2 different groups (i.e., 2 list elements) instead of one group (i.e., 1 list element)?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

Data <- read.table(h=T, text =
"study   sample_id var1.var2 effect
Mecartty        1 L2V.L2L      1
Mecartty        1 L2G.L2L      2
Mecartty        2 L2R.L2V      3
Mecartty        2 L2R.L2G      4
Mecartty        2 L2V.L2G      5
Larson          1 L2R.L2G      6
Larson          1 L2R.L2L      7
Larson          1 L2G.L2L      8
Larson          2 L2R.L2G      9
Larson          2 L2R.L2L      10
Larson          2 L2G.L2L      11")
#====
foo2 <- function(dat, study_col, ...) {
  
  dot_cols <- ensyms(...)
  str_cols <- purrr::map_chr(dot_cols, rlang::as_string)
  
  dat %>%
    dplyr::select({{study_col}}, !!! dot_cols) %>%
    dplyr::group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(grp = across(all_of(str_cols), ~ {
      tmp <- n_distinct(.)
      case_when(tmp  == 1 ~ 1, tmp == n() ~ 2, tmp >1 & tmp < n() ~ 3,  TRUE ~ 4)
    }) %>%
      purrr::reduce(stringr::str_c, collapse="")) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup(.) %>%
    dplyr::group_split(grp, .keep = FALSE)
  
}
## EXAMPLE OF USE:

foo2(Data, study, sample_id, var1.var2)
#-----Output:   EXPECT 1 LIST  ELEMENT BUT GIVES 2?!
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  study    sample_id var1.var2
  <chr>        <int> <chr>    
1 Mecartty         1 L2V.L2L  
2 Mecartty         1 L2G.L2L  
3 Mecartty         2 L2R.L2V  
4 Mecartty         2 L2R.L2G  
5 Mecartty         2 L2V.L2G  

[[2]]
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  study  sample_id var1.var2
  <chr>      <int> <chr>    
1 Larson         1 L2R.L2G  
2 Larson         1 L2R.L2L  
3 Larson         1 L2G.L2L  
4 Larson         2 L2R.L2G  
5 Larson         2 L2R.L2L  
6 Larson         2 L2G.L2L
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `foo2()` ends with a `dplyr::group_split()` which is going to break up the dataframe into a list of dataframes based on what the contents of `grp` variable contains.

If you take off that last bit of the function (and keep the column `grp`), you can see what exists before the `group_split()`:

```
foo2 <- function(dat, study_col, ...) {
  
  dot_cols <- ensyms(...)
  str_cols <- purrr::map_chr(dot_cols, rlang::as_string)
  dat %>%
    dplyr::select({{study_col}}, !!! dot_cols) %>%
    dplyr::group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(grp = across(all_of(str_cols), ~ {
      tmp <- n_distinct(.)
      case_when(tmp  == 1 ~ 1, tmp == n() ~ 2, tmp >1 & tmp < n() ~ 3,  TRUE ~ 4)
    }) %>%
      purrr::reduce(stringr::str_c, collapse="")) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup(.) #%>%
    # dplyr::group_split(grp, .keep = FALSE)
  
}

> foo2(Data, study, sample_id, var1.var2)
# A tibble: 11 × 4
   study    sample_id var1.var2 grp  
   <chr>        <int> <chr>     <chr>
 1 Mecartty         1 L2V.L2L   32   
 2 Mecartty         1 L2G.L2L   32   
 3 Mecartty         2 L2R.L2V   32   
 4 Mecartty         2 L2R.L2G   32   
 5 Mecartty         2 L2V.L2G   32   
 6 Larson           1 L2R.L2G   33   
 7 Larson           1 L2R.L2L   33   
 8 Larson           1 L2G.L2L   33   
 9 Larson           2 L2R.L2G   33   
10 Larson           2 L2R.L2L   33   
11 Larson           2 L2G.L2L   33
```

You can see `grp` has two values: `c("32", "33")`.  If you deconstruct the `mutate(grp)` further up, you can see how it is getting those two values, and the fact that you have two values is what causes `group_split(grp, .keep = FALSE)` to give you a list of 2 instead of a single dataframe output.

### Added as edit:

Just to take it a bit further, I commented out the `case_when()` to make sure I understood the raw data before it modified it:

```
foo2 <- function(dat, study_col, ...) {
  
  dot_cols <- ensyms(...)
  str_cols <- purrr::map_chr(dot_cols, rlang::as_string)
  dat %>%
    dplyr::select({{study_col}}, !!! dot_cols) %>%
    dplyr::group_by({{study_col}}) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(grp = across(all_of(str_cols), ~ {
      tmp <- n_distinct(.)
      # case_when(tmp  == 1 ~ 1, tmp == n() ~ 2, tmp >1 & tmp < n() ~ 3,  TRUE ~ 4)
    }) %>%
      purrr::reduce(stringr::str_c, collapse="")) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup(.) #%>%
    # dplyr::group_split(grp, .keep = FALSE)
  
}

> foo2(Data, study, sample_id, var1.var2)
# A tibble: 11 × 4
   study    sample_id var1.var2 grp  
   <chr>        <int> <chr>     <chr>
 1 Mecartty         1 L2V.L2L   25   
 2 Mecartty         1 L2G.L2L   25   
 3 Mecartty         2 L2R.L2V   25   
 4 Mecartty         2 L2R.L2G   25   
 5 Mecartty         2 L2V.L2G   25   
 6 Larson           1 L2R.L2G   23   
 7 Larson           1 L2R.L2L   23   
 8 Larson           1 L2G.L2L   23   
 9 Larson           2 L2R.L2G   23   
10 Larson           2 L2R.L2L   23   
11 Larson           2 L2G.L2L   23
```

Now the `grp` column shows the `n_distinct(.)` as a two digit number (which is a concatenation of that function's result coming from `sample_id` and `var1.var2`.  Since it's grouped by `study`, Mecartty shows unique `sample_id` of `c(1L, 2L)`, which is 2, and is the same for Larson, but the `case_when()` converts that to a "3".  For `var1.var2`, Mecartty has 5 distinct values on 5 rows/observations, triggering a "2" from `case_when()`.  For Larson, however, the values repeat, giving 3 distinct values on 6 rows/observations, triggering a "3".  This is how you get the `c("32", "33")` that splits your dataframe in 2 elements.